# d3 : Synchronize mouseover for two plots

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have two plots (svg1 and svg2) which are identical in size. I want to synchronize the mouseover ie. when the user mouse overs over sgv1 at point [x0,y0] I want the show the values as overlays on both the plots. My problem is that I am extracting the x0,y0 and the value from the raw data and can print it via console.log but there is no overlay. Here are the corresponding snippets from my code:

```
<script>
...
function drawplots(plot){
    var focus1,focus2;
    if (plot==1) {thisdata=data1; thissvg=svg1;focus=focus1;} 
    else {thisdata=data2; thissvg=svg2;focus=focus2;}
    ...
    ...
    focus=thissvg.append("g").attr("class","focus").style("display","none")
          .append("circle").attr("r",4.5).append("text")
          .attr("x",9).attr("dy",".35em");

    thissvg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "overlay")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .on("mouseover", function() { focus.style("display", null  ); })
    .on("mouseout" , function() { focus.style("display", "none"); })
    .on("mousemove", function() {
        var x0 = scalex0.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]);
        var index=bisectdata(thisdata,x0);
        var y0 = (thisdata[index])[1];
        var ypos=scaley0(y0);
        var xpos=scalex0(x0);
        var fe = d3.format(".1f keV");
        var fs = d3.format("s");
        var textvalue="[ "+fe(x0)+" , "+fs(y0)+" ]";
        console.log(plot,textvalue);
        focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + xpos + "," + ypos + ")");
        focus.select("text").text(textvalue);
    });
}
...
</script>

<body>
<div id="plot1">
<div id="plot2">

svg1=d3.selectAll("#plot1").append("svg").attr("width",width).attr("height",height);
svg2=d3.selectAll("#plot2").append("svg").attr("width",width).attr("height",height);

</body>
```

So how do I use the same function to have mouseover events on two different svgs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I have misread your question, isn't it as simple as...

```
function mouseover (){
    // this will be the element the event is fired on
    //get the position using d3.event if relevant
    rect1.style({
        opacity: 1
    });
    // perform some other translation manipulation here if needed
    rect2.style({
        opacity: 1
    })
   //or you could d3...selectAll('rect') and then perform operations on all at the same time
}
var rect1 = d3...append("rect").on('mouseover', mouseover);
var rect2 = d3...append("rect").on('mouseover', mouseover);
```

And then a similar shared function for mouseout.